# How to set the Regular Expression Validation for the Double property using Enterprise Library validation Block.?

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Techies...

I have the following class for Employee.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I just wants to set the Validation for the double property Salary to accept only Numbers.

I tried like the below.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="validation" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Configuration.ValidationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
<validation>
    <type name="namespace.Model.Common.Masters.Employee" defaultRuleset="SaveRuleset"
        assemblyName="namespace.Model.Common.Masters, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <ruleset name="SaveRuleset">
            <properties>
                <property name="Salary">
                    <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.OrCompositeValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                        messageTemplate="Salary accept numbers only." name="Or Composite Validator">
                        <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.NotNullValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                            negated="true" name="Not Null Validator" />
                        <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.RegexValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                            pattern="^[0-9]" name="Regular Expression Validator" />
                    </validator>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </ruleset>
    </type>
</validation>
</configuration>
```

Do I have to using Regular Expression? And Also note I could not set the RangeValidator.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance,

Regards,
Sravan.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your regular expression is just verifying that what is entered starts with a digit.  Try `pattern="^\d*$"`
The RangeValidator will try to use the IComparable interface implementation, which won't do what you need for string input.
The Or Composite validator combined with the negated Not Null validator function to make salary 'optional'.  It's not clear if that's what you want.